# tar gzip slowing down server

Tags: backup, tar, gzip

I have a backup script that:

1. compress some files
2. generate md5
3. copy the compressed file to another server.
4. the other server finishes comparing MD5 (to find copy errors).

Here it's the core script:

```
nice -n 15 tar -czvf $BKP $PATH_BKP/*.* \
| xargs -I '{}' sh -c "test -f '{}' && md5sum '{}'" \
| tee $MD5
scp -l 80000 $BKP $SCP_BKP
scp $MD5 $SCP_BKP
```

This routine got CPU at 90% at gzip routine, slowing down the production server. I tried to add a `nice -n 15` but server still hangs.

I've already read [1](https://serverfault.com/questions/121848/tar-cfz-versus-tar-cf-gzip-are-they-different-or-how-to-improve-a-bac) but the conversation didn't help me.

What is the best approach to solve this issue ?
I am open to new architectures/solutions :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use nice, you change the priority, but this will have a noticeable impact only if the CPU is close to 100% usage.

The server becomes slow, in your case, not because of the CPU usage, but because of the I/O on the storage. Use `ionice` to change the I/O priority and keep the `nice` for CPU priority.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mircea. But when I issue a top, gzip is at 95% CPU. Is this not a measure that the problem is on CPU ? How can I measure the IO ?

Comment: Which CPU do you use ?

Comment: It's kvm/qemu virtual machine. The host is an XEON 8 cores but the guest VM has just one core available. The machine is very fast. With 50 active users, the CPU never get 10%. The only exception is the damn  gzip :(

Comment: For I/O usage you can use: vmstat, iostat, dstat.  I prefer dstat: `dstat -tam --top-io 10`

Comment: If you have kvm the information reported by the top and other similar utilities could be inaccurate especially if you are overcommiting the host CPU. I would also investigate the problem from the host server.

Comment: It was an IO problem! I solved the problem using a faster disk/controller.

Comment: Thank you for the feed back. I am glad that you found the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using *chrt* to change the scheduling policy of the tar program to SCHED_BATCH.

As per the man page *sched_setscheduler(2)*

> SCHED_BATCH: Scheduling batch processes
>          (Since  Linux 2.6.16.)  SCHED_BATCH can only be used at static priority
>          0.  This policy is similar to SCHED_OTHER  in  that  it  schedules  the
>          process  according  to  its dynamic priority (based on the nice value).
>          The difference is that this policy will cause the scheduler  to  always
>          assume  that the process is CPU-intensive.  Consequently, the scheduler
>          will apply a small scheduling penalty with respect to wakeup behaviour,
>          so that this process is mildly disfavored in scheduling decisions.
>
> ```
>    This policy is useful for workloads that are noninteractive, but do not
>    want to lower their nice value, and for workloads that want a determin‐
>    istic scheduling policy without interactivity causing extra preemptions
>    (between the workload's tasks).
> ```

If your still out of luck you could try SCHED_IDLE instead. This would make this program only wake up if there is nothing else to run.

This changes the tar line to this for batch:

```
nice -n 15 chrt -b tar -czvf $BKP $PATH_BKP/*.* \
```

Comment: Thanks Mlfe. It seems interesting. But the server is always running something. Is it possible that tar/gzip never wake up and routine keeps running "ad eternum" ?

Comment: If your CPU averages are < 100% at a given interval. The server is not always running something, so I wouldnt worry about that.

Comment: I tried chrt but it didn't change the slowness. But I learned another Linux architecture detail. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using *[pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/)* instead of gzip?

Comment: This would probably make the situation worse.

Comment: @mgorven Not necessarily. It depends on how may cores he has and the workload.